# FormData - AXIOS - FORM on submit Post is showing Bad Request - ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, axios, form-data

I have a form which is having a file and submit button once the form submitted i have to post the image file to server. After submitting the form i am getting Bad Request Error below is my code also the error i have shared

```
 uploadCategoryImages = () => {
 const formData = new FormData(); 
 console.log(categoryImageArray)   
 formData.append('images', categoryImageArray)
 api.post('/api/v1/addimage/category/2', formData)
 .then((res) => {                   
 console.log("Successs", res)
 })
 .catch((error) => {
 console.log("Error :", error);
 })
 }
```

categoryImageArray is the array which is having base64 image

```
["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD… 
ed+q879V536rzv1XnfqvO/Ved+q879UKjBxwvXGsf+cf/2Q=="]
```

and the error which i am getting is

```
Error : Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (createError.js:16)
at settle (settle.js:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```